# Is there a version of the inverse function theorem for a function $f:R^m\rightarrow R^n$ with $n>m$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, inverse-function-theorem

in a research project, I need to apply some version of the inverse function theorem to a function  $f:R^m\rightarrow R^n$ with $n>m$. More specifically, I have $\gamma=f(t)$, where $\gamma$ has higher dimension. I need conditions under which $t=f^{-1}(\gamma)$ exists. However, the versions of inverse function theorems I found online (such as [https://students.iiserkol.ac.in/~sp17rs038/blog/Inverse%20Function%20Theorem.pdf](https://students.iiserkol.ac.in/%7Esp17rs038/blog/Inverse%20Function%20Theorem.pdf)) have $m=n$.

If you could provide a specific reference that satisfies my need, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't have to be.   A linear transformation from $R^m$ to $R^n$, with n> m, maps all of $R^m$ to a subspace of dimension m in $R^n$. 

Just use that subspace instead of all of $R^n$.

Comment: @user247327 Thanks! This is helpful. Should I just replace the condition that $Df(t)$ is invertible with the condition that $Df(t)$ has rank equal to $m$?

Comment: There is the implicit function theorem.